# Why inputElement.maxLength returns -1?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, w3c

I wonder why default maxLength/minLength property for HTMLInputElement is set to -1 by default.

There is also confusing behavior like below:

1. Example

```html
<input type="text" />
```

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input');
console.log(inputElement.maxLength) // -1
```

---

2. I set `maxLength` programatically

```js
inputElement.maxLength = 2;
console.log(inputElement.maxLength) // 2
```

and html will reflect as

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="2" />
```

---

3. I remove `maxlength="2"` manually from devtools.

```html
<input type="text" />
```

I get

```js
console.log(inputElement.maxLength) // undefined
```

can someone tell me why is that? There is no such a thing in [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-fe-maxlength), but i can see that every browser is pretty consistent in this.

[Edit]
3. is wrong in this example, it is return -1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75541575/10465908

Comment: I think -1 just represents that there is no limit for the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answer to my original question is https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#limited-to-only-non-negative-numbers as `maxLength` is type [`long`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element:dom-input-maxlength).

But I discovered some interesting things during the investigation:

1. [WebKit](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/a0e54048967bef913b7f78d9037655a7c8299c7c#diff-9fb71b6fa7156160059b0216d05933e621d422df2b20f72ad7399eb946b8ba04R16) returns `-1` but real `maxlength` is [524288](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/a0e54048967bef913b7f78d9037655a7c8299c7c/Source/WebCore/html/HTMLInputElement.cpp#L92), other engines seems not have this limitation.
2. It was `524288` in other browsers way back
3. During IDL attributes spec, they all decided to return `-1`

Answer (score 2):

Insightful question.

Well, according to the official docs of the Web, the [World Wide Web](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-maxlength),

> The default value for this attribute is an unlimited number

And as we all know computers cannot represent infinity.

A big number (like 1 billion) is big but still not infinity or "unlimited". So the best way was to choose a negative number (-1). **Just in this way, they are not setting a max length constraint on the input.**

However, please note that they decided to do it just from their side (to do this workaround) i.e. we cannot set explicitly the -1. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the step 3 i'm getting `-1` when i remove attribute in chrome 110